# If the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent, the limit is zero, but $\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm using Stewart's Calculus for learning series. It's already been wrong once.

However it now says "If the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent, $\lim_{n\to\infty} = 0$."

However, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ConvergenceOfSeries.aspx Example 2 shows that the limit is $\frac{3}{4}$ yet it is convergent, specifically the sum is also $\frac{3}{4}$ and I'm just confused now.

Comment: If the series $\sum a_n$ converges, the limit of the *sequence* $(a_n)$ is zero.

Comment: What are you taking the limit of?  It is missing.  I suspect it is $a_n$, not the sum.  The point is that if $a_n$ doesn't go to zero, the sum will not converge.

Comment: That's precisely what happened in the example @RossMillikan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the example you cite shows that the limit of the *partial sums* $S_N = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$ is $\dfrac{3}{4}$, not that the limit of the *terms* themselves is $\dfrac{3}{4}$. The statement in quotations is correct and not that hard to show.

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent; that is, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n := \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}S_N$ exists and is equal to $S$ for some $S \in \mathbb{R}$. Now note that $S_N-S_{N-1} = a_N$. Taking the limit as $N$ approaches infinity we have

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}a_N = \lim_{N\to\infty}(S_N - S_{N-1}) = \lim_{N\to\infty}S_N - \lim_{N\to\infty}S_{N-1} = S - S = 0.$$

Therefore, if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_N = 0$.